# by using split function of sql get correct result

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using Oracle DB.

```
select split('123,45,6,7',1,',') from dual ;

---------------------------------------------------------------------
result
123
---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

In above query only 1st value(123) will be in result.
Is there any way to fetch all values from above query.

I want result like below in one query:

```
result 
123 
45
6
7
```

Comment: Hover over the sql-tag underneath your question. It says: *"Questions should include code examples, table structure, sample data, **and a tag for the DBMS implementation (e.g. MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, MS SQL Server, IBM DB2)***"...

Comment: Please tag your question with the actual RDBMS (product and version). The tag `sql` is not enough...

Comment: Use `unnest(string_to_array(...)` in Postgres

Comment: @TT select split('123,45,6,7',1,',') from dual;  This is a simple sql do you really require table structure and all for this?

Comment: Hi Shine, the text in bold is what I wanted to highlight. The rest of that is "when required" for the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way

```
 DECLARE @Str VARCHAR(100)= '123,45,6,7' ;WITH _CTE (_Str , _RemStr) AS
   (
   SELECT SUBSTRING(@Str,0,CHARINDEX(',',@Str)) ,
          SUBSTRING(@Str,CHARINDEX(',',@Str)+1,LEN(@Str))
   UNION ALL
   SELECT CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(',',_RemStr) = 0 THEN _RemStr ELSE SUBSTRING(_RemStr,0,CHARINDEX(',',_RemStr)) END,          
          CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(',',_RemStr) = 0 THEN '' ELSE SUBSTRING(_RemStr,CHARINDEX(',',_RemStr)+1,LEN(_RemStr)) END
   FROM _CTE           
   WHERE _RemStr <> ''
)
SELECT _Str
FROM _CTE
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below function for Split string

```
Create FUNCTION [dbo].[SplitString]
(
    @INPUT nvarchar(max)
)
RETURNS 
@ParsedList table
(
    OrderID int
)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @OrderID varchar(10), @Pos int

    SET @INPUT = LTRIM(RTRIM(@INPUT))+ ','
    SET @Pos = CHARINDEX(',', @INPUT, 1)

    IF REPLACE(@INPUT, ',', '') <> ''
    BEGIN
        WHILE @Pos > 0
        BEGIN
            SET @OrderID = LTRIM(RTRIM(LEFT(@INPUT, @Pos - 1)))
            IF @OrderID <> ''
            BEGIN
                INSERT INTO @ParsedList (OrderID) 
                VALUES (CAST(@OrderID AS int)) --Use Appropriate conversion
            END
            SET @INPUT = RIGHT(@INPUT, LEN(@INPUT) - @Pos)
            SET @Pos = CHARINDEX(',', @INPUT, 1)

        END
    END 
    RETURN
END
```

And Execute below

```
Select * from [SplitString]('123,45,6,7')
```